# Using Nservice bus to send messages from Web application to Desktop windows application

Tags: web-applications, notifications, push-notification, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I Have web application and another Desktop application , both are .Net applications. User can add news and upload documents to the web application ,
I need my Desktop application to get Notified about this added things on the web application. I had invistigated in this and i figured out that i should implement a publisher/Subscriber pattern and i found also that this could be implemented using Nservice Bus.

All what i need is to find a good article that implements a sample similar to what i had explained here because i am new in this and i don't kow how to start .

Comment: of course if anybody have a better approch that will be welcomed, I just want to implement the Idea

Comment: Have you thought about using SignalR? There is C# client so for now you could use it and if In the future you would like to change desktop app to webapp you can still use it.

Comment: Is it easy to use SignalR , as i spent long time to try to figure out how does it work , and i have no time to start studing another thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having another endpoint (on your backend tier) that will process a command from your web application and then publish an event, the desktop application will subscribe to the event published by the backend component.

Here is more information about [publishing events from web applications](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/publishing-from-web-applications)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any idea if there is more than one instance of the subscriber installed on different users machine , do all this instances will receive a copy of the message that was published by the publisher ???

Comment: Is this on Azure? so you have competing consumers on the same logical queue?

Comment: No it is not on Azure ,, i am using MSMQ queue to save the published messages on the server and there will be multiple instances of subscriber on diifernt machines ,,,but the server have subscribtion message from each one

Comment: In this case, yes all subscribers on all machines will receive a copy of the published message.  [You can find more info here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/)